# Unable to retrieve HttpHeaderResponse

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have an issue with my angular application in order i am unable to retrieve the data in the HttpResponseHeader.
this is my response:

[image]

my service code :

```js
getUsers(page?: number, itemsPerPage?: number): Observable<PaginatedResult<User[]>> {
    const url = this.baseUrl + '/users/';
    const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<User[]> = new PaginatedResult<User[]>();

    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (page != null && itemsPerPage != null) {

        params = new HttpParams()
                         .set('pageNumber', page.toString())
                         .set('pageSize', itemsPerPage.toString());

    }
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users', { observe: 'response', params})
        .pipe(
            map(response => {
                paginatedResult.result = response.body;
                if (response.headers.get('Pagination') != null) {
                    paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('Pagination'));
                }
                return paginatedResult;
            })
         );
}
```

in the cors backend configuration i made :

```cs
app.UseCors(p=>p.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake on your header key name.
Rename your "Accoss-Control-Expose-Headers" to "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"